# Overview page in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I would like to create an overview page for a user after he has submitted a form. Since, some other data, like logged in user data would be auto appended to the data the user submitted, I would like to create a page, which would be shown to the user before he completely submits the form, but after he has input the initial data.

How can this be accomplished in Zend Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the form data in a session namespace.

Eg

1. Action #1

   - Display form, submits to self
   - On POST, validate form & store values in session namespace
   - Redirect to Action #2
2. Action #2

   - Get form data from session namespace
   - Display captured data and confirmation form (confirm / cancel)
   - Validate confirmation form (a Hash element is a good choice in this form too)
   - Do stuff